# Why this function is causing no error?

Tags: c++

```
void removeDuplicateWithHashtable(LinkedListElement<char> *head)
{
    LinkedListElement<char> *runner = head;
    LinkedListElement<char> *previous = nullptr;
    hash_map<char, bool> record;
    while (runner) {
        if (record.count(runner->Data) == 0) {
            pair<char, bool> item(runner->Data,true);
            record.insert(item);
        }else
        {
            free(runner);
            previous->Next = runner->Next;
        }
        previous=runner;
        runner=runner->Next;
    }
}
```

Initially I thought there would be an error. Because in `free(runner)`, if i free the memory, i can not access runner->Next.
But GCC compiler ran successfully.

Actually if i change free to delete runner, it is also correct.
can i ask the reason may be free or delete just tell you the memory is available no actually clear data inside, so you can also access Next.
And can i ask how to improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a compilation error but the problem (undefined behaviour) will manifest itself at runtime. If you choose to call `free` on unallocated memory the compiler will not stop you.

Comment: Actually if i change free to delete runner, it is also correct.
can i ask the reason may be free or delete just tell you the memory is available no actually clear data inside, so you can also access Next.
And can i ask how to improve it?

Comment: @Hypnoz It is not a question of `delete` or `free`  - it will not be a compiler error either way. The simple fact is you should not attempt to release unallocated memory.

Answer (score 4):

Such logical errors cannot be detected by a compiler! Instead, the program has undefined behavior, which can include running seemingly OK, crashing, or producing all sorts of garbage. There are a lot of (and I can't stress that enough, like, a LOT) situations that result in undefined behavior

Comment: "cannot be detected" - in general: yes. in this case: certainly doable.

Comment: Actually if i change free to delete runner, it is also correct.
can i ask the reason may be free or delete just tell you the memory is available no actually clear data inside, so you can also access Next.
And can i ask how to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your program **can work fine** since `free()` only marks some memory as free, but it does not actually overwrite it. Owing to this, the chances are **your solution will run correctly most of the time** as in your function you are not using any new memory. (At least in single threaded environment.)

On the other hand, I would go and **fundamentally change** the function like this:

```
template<typename _Tp>
void unique(forward_list<_Tp>& list)
{
  unordered_map<_Tp, bool> record;
  auto la=list.before_begin();
  for(auto it=list.begin(); it!=list.end(); ++it) 
  {
    if(record.find(*it)==record.end())
      record[*++la] = true;
    else
      list.erase_after(la);
  }
}
```

You can even go as far as writing this:

```
template<typename _Tp>
void unique(forward_list<_Tp>& list)
{
  unordered_map<_Tp, bool> record;
  auto la=list.before_begin();
  for(auto e: list) 
  {
    if(record.find(e)==record.end())
      record[*++la] = true;
    else
      list.erase_after(la);
  }
}
```

But I think that can be a bit too much, as it does not reflect that we need to go one element after an other.

---

**My reasons for the fundamental change:**

1. In C++ `free()` is called `delete`. It is used in pair with `new` (which is used in c++ instead of `malloc()` or `calloc()`). `delete` is used like this:

   delete runner;
   // and new is used like this:
   Some_type *p = new Some_type();
2. STL has already a LinkedList, so it makes sense to use that. It is called [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). You want to use [`erase_after`, with a nice example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/erase_after).
3. You want to use std::unsorted_map instead of hash_map (again, since it is in STL). The best is always the std solution.
4. One of the main purpose of classes is to hide away necessary pointer activity, so in function headers I would rather use references instead of pointers, so at least your function should be

   `void removeDuplicateWithHashtable(LinkedListElement<char>& head)`

Comment: "we use references instead of pointers" - To be fair, use of pointers is perfectly valid C++.

Comment: I disagree. Pointers can be avoided all the time in non-library code, since we have shared_ptr and unique_ptr. I hope you like my sample codes ;)

Comment: Also, using pointers in function headers is pretty confusing: you don't know whether you need to call delete on a pointer afterwards...

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs There are lots of cases in C++ where pointers are necessary.  Any time you're implementing a dynamic structure, for example.  Or anytime you need to navigate between objects.  Having a reference member also means that an object can't be assignable.

Comment: Yeah, of course, there are situations where pointers are unavoidable, but that does rarely include function headers and most of the time one is better off using shared_ptr rather than a raw ptr. But you also avoid pointers when it is possible, don't you? Also, most of the dynamic structures can be built using some stl as fundamental pieces. (All the others I consider library building, really...) I try and correct my answer taking your opinion into consideration.

Comment: Actually if i change free to delete runner, it is also correct.
can i ask the reason may be free or delete just tell you the memory is available no actually clear data inside, so you can also access Next.
And can i ask how to improve it?

Comment: Sure, see my reasons, also I tried to explain some improvements, completely rewrote my answer. I also hope it is now more appealing for others.