# C++ Address of lambda objects as parameters to functions

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

From my experience it seems that either:

- A lambda expression created inside a function call is destroyed just after the invocation
- Calling a function that expects a `std::function` creates a temporary object (std::function) out of the lambda, and that object is destroyed after invocation

This behavior can be observed with the following snippet of code:

```
const function<void()>* pointer;

void a(const function<void()> & f)
{
    pointer = &f;
}

void b()
{
    (*pointer)();
}

int main()
{
    int value = 1;
    std::cout << &value << std::endl;

    // 1: this works    
    function<void()> f = [&] () { std::cout << &value << std::endl; };
    a(f);

    // 2: this doesn't
    a([&] () { std::cout << &value << std::endl; });

    /* modify the stack*/
    char data[1024];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        data[i] = i % 4; 

    b();

    return 0;
}
```

What exactly s actually happening in the second case?
Is there a correct way to call `a()` without creating an explicit `std::function` object?

**Edit:**:
This both versions (1 and 2) compile just right but result in different outputs:

Version 1:

```
0x7fffa70148c8
0x7fffa70148c8
```

Version 2:

```
0x7fffa70148c8
0
```

Comment: What do you mean that the second case "doesn't work"? Does it compile? Does it crash? Does it write out "doesn't work" to your printer?

Comment: @jalf: You forgot: Does it halt and catch fire.

Comment: /*modify the stack*/ Most compilers preallocate the necessary space for **all** local variables upon function entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a temporary, it will be gone at the end of the line. This means storing a pointer to it is a bad idea, as you correctly stated.

If you want to store a pointer to a `std::function` (or anything else really), you need to make sure it's lifetime doesn't end before you stop using the pointer. This means that you really do need a named object of type `std::function`.

As to what is happening in the second case: You create a temporary lambda to be passed to the function. Since the function expects a `std::function`, a temporary `std::function` will be created from the lambda. Both of those will be destroyed at the end of the line. Therefore you now have a pointer to an already destroyed temporary, which means that trying to use the pointed to object will bring you firmly into undefined behaviour territory.

Comment: well, this is not necessarily true for lambdas as they are rewritten to "real" functions so they stay in memory, at the same address.

Comment: At the end of the containing _full expression_ actually. In this case, that is roughly that line.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs: Are you sure about that? A lambda can be implicitely converted to a function pointer (so the function is somewhere, that much is true), but will the lambda actually be rewritten to be identical to that function pointer? seems wasteful in terms of missed inlining opportunity. Either way, it doesn't matter, since the important point is that the `std::function` is destroyed

Comment: Not 100% :) but I can't break the code. Not with even adding rude optimization flags. I've seen (worse) programs which would run just fine for sure(!) on single-threaded environments.

Comment: In fact, here it is: [Why this function is causing no error?] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740258/why-this-function-is-causing-no-error/13741388#13741388). :))

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs: Looking closer I must correct my statement: The lambda has a capture, as such it can't be converted to a plain (dump) function, but must remain a capture. For not beeing able to break the code: Well it is undefined behaviour, not automatically breaking behaviour. I tried it in ideone. Interestingly enough it breaks when the value instead of the address of `value` is printed (look [here](http://ideone.com/AjAWYk)).

Comment: Yes, indeed, I also realized that I needed to change my statement and deleted what I wrote as an answer. It was an interesting discussion, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

It's okay for *stateless lambdas*. Stateless lambdas have an implicit conversion to function pointer type.

Also, there is *always* an implicit conversion to std::function<> regardless of the actual callable type.

**There are problems with keeping a pointer to temporaries, though**. I hadn't noticed that on first reading of the code.

That has nothing to do with std::function, of course.

Comment: It is ok to store a pointer to a temporary `std::function`, if the object wrapped inside the `function` is a functionpointer?

Comment: No. Pointers to temporaries are always bad. You know, that has nothing to do with std::function<> really

Comment: **I** know that, but your answer seems to imply that it is (so you might want to change the wording ;))

Comment: @Grizzly I take it you should refresh you browser more often :) Sorry for missing that on the first round, though

Answer (score 0):

Temporary objects are destroyed at the end of the statement they are created in.  You have just demonstrated this with a lambda.

The std function you pass the first time is not a temporary, so it lasts as long as the variable.  It actually stores a copy of the temporary.

To have your lamdas last more than a line, you need to store it somewhere and have its lifetime determined.

There are many ways to do this.  Std function is a type erasure based way to do the storage -- ie, store a std function instead of a pointer to a std function.  Change the type of `pointer` to being a non pointer (and non const), get rid of the `&` when you assign to it, and call it directly.

In general avoid taking and storing the address of const reference function parameters as temporary bind to them, unless you catch the rvalue reference possibility in another overload.

Comment: Any way to store the lambda without having the runtime overhead of the type erasure provided by std::function?

Comment: @joaorafael In a function, auto deduces the type.  In a template class wrapping the call, a function based creator can deduce the lambda type and passing to the class so the class can store a non erased lambda.  A philosophical approach can ask you if you know this is a performance bottleneck, and if your efforts are not better spent elsewhere.  The code that stores and uses the lambda needs to be a function of the lambdas type if you want to avoid type erasure overhead.